# Reporting Services: Getting report meta info (page height, width, orientation etc.)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

In a current project I need to get report meta-information such as page pixe height/ width or page orientation. 
Ideally I would like to achieve this information before actually rendering the report itself (by using `RenderExecutionService.Render2` method).

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the web service offers methods to query the meta information as is - it may be considered *part of* the report as opposed to *meta* info. In any case I think you should be able to use the [`GetItemDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.getitemdefinition%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) method to retrieve the RDL. In the RDL it should be easy to extract this meta info using xpath or perhaps even a regex. (Note: the RDL file is just an XML file.)